# Can I automatically copy a directory after iTunes rips a CD?

Tags: itunes

I'm after a simple way to back up the directory created by iTunes when it rips a music CD to add to its library.

Is there any way to have iTunes use AppleScript somehow to copy the directory across once it's finished ripping?

**Update:** For clarity I have multiple systems to play my music, I rip CDs using my Macbook so I can listen via iTunes when I'm not at home, but I also have Sonos installed which plays music from my NAS, so when I'm not at home the family can still listen to music.

I'd like to rip a CD, & copy it to the NAS automatically so it's available to Sonos (and via DNLA for the PS3 or other clients I might have in the future)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? syncing between two macs, or syncing to a NAS or just to backup?

Comment: Is there anything useful at [Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/)?

Comment: @CajunLuke I can't see anything, but it might give me a starting point. I could switch off automatic ripping & write a script to rip, then copy.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on [Keeping two iTunes libraries in sync](http://guides.macrumors.com/Keeping_2_iTunes_Libraries_in_Sync) is one method that uses the rsync unix tool to perform a directory by directory and file by file compare, so you wouldnt need to do much except create the script and run it periodically.

Add on to that the ability to run [rsync as a daemon](http://jafdip.com/index.php/2011/11/20/how-to-setup-rsyncd-on-mac-os-x/) and this becomes a completely automated process.